# How to integrate both FB and Google plus in ios?

Tags: google-plus, ios7.1

I wanna integrate fb loging and google plus loging to my ios app. I have alredy integrated the fbloging. Now I want to integrate the Google plus loging.Now In appdelegate I have alredy this delegate.

`

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{


return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
              sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
```

}`

Now I want to add these codes to the same delegates for Google plus.

`

```
 return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                  annotation:annotation];`
```

How can I add this code to the same delegate without affecting to the FB loging.

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: A class can conform to more than one protocol at the same time.  What's the issue you have?

Comment: I want to add the below code into the same delegate. For the fb logging I have alredy added the code. so I need to add the 2nd return code also. But how can I return 2 things within the same delegate

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could just chain the calls together with:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation {

    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication] &&
           [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];
}
```

I'm not sure if that will work though, but it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    BOOL returnURL;
    NSString *urlSTR=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    NSArray *tempArr=[urlSTR componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *tempStr=[tempArr objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([tempStr isEqualToString:@"fbYOUR_APP_ID:"]) {
        BOOL urlWasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                      fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                                          NSLog(@"Unhandled deep link: %@", url);
                                          // Parse the incoming URL to look for a target_url parameter
                                          NSString *query = [url fragment];
                                          if (!query) {
                                              query = [url query];
                                          }
                                          NSDictionary *params = [self parseURLParams:query];
                                          // Check if target URL exists
                                          NSString *targetURLString = [params valueForKey:@"target_url"];
                                          if (targetURLString) {
                                              // Show the incoming link in an alert
                                              // Your code to direct the user to the appropriate flow within your app goes here
                                              [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Received link:"
                                                                          message:targetURLString
                                                                         delegate:self
                                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                                          }
                                      }];

        returnURL=urlWasHandled;

    }
else if ([tempStr isEqualToString:@"igINSTAGRAM_APP_ID:"]){
        returnURL=[self.instagram handleOpenURL:url];
    }
else{
        returnURL= [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                             annotation:annotation];
    }

    return returnURL;
}
```

Comment: Now you can Integrate multiple social Media platform to your iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *) application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
BOOL wasHandled=false;
if ([url.scheme hasPrefix:@"fb"])
 {
wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
//Facebook callback
}
else//Google Plus callback
{
wasHandled=  [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
return wasHandled;
}
```